# template gets loaded before @Input gets fully intiialized

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application, Mine html template gets initialized before my @Input which is of object gets fully loaded.

My @Input in my ts has been defined as below :

```
 @Input() conversation:any;
```

In html file, the file has been defined as below:

```
{{ conversatin | json}}
    <div *ngIf="conversation">
        <span *ngIf="conversation.participants[conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase()].firstName">
                    {{ conversation.participants[conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase()].firstName+" "+conversation.participants[conversation.updatedBy].lastName }}
                </span> </div>
```

When I am printing the data is coming properly as per below for input conversation.

```
{ "currentBox": 1, "internalId": 1499, "subject": "hello", "unreadMessageCount": null, "updateDate": 1518607107, "managerCode": null, "portfolioId": null, "updatedBy": "cli", "messages": [ { "internalId": 2239, "threadId": 1499, "body": "\n hello", "fromUserId": "cli", "creationDate": 1518607107, "createdBy": "cli", "readStatuses": [], "read": false, "statusMessage": "message sent 2/14/2018, 4:48:27 PM" } ], "participants": { "ebb": { "internalId": 50, "userId": "ebtst1", "firstName": "dd1", "lastName": "dd", "dateJoin": 1518607053, "dateLeft": 0, "invitedBy": "rr", "initials": "dd" }, "cli": { "internalId": 51, "userId": "cli", "firstName": "Cl", "lastName": "Fr", "dateJoin": 1518607053, "dateLeft": 0, "invitedBy": "Eb", "initials": "CF" } }, "isComplete": true }
```

I also tried defining @input as type object but no luck.

Comment: Guys, anyone can help me on this?

Comment: didn't `*ngIf ` solve your problem? I mean, now the html is not loaded before your object, right?

Comment: No, *ngIf does not solve any issues, however it has previous values [ngOnChanages] the object which gets formatted once it is coming from @Input